# System stalled after "systemctl isolate reboot.target"

Tags: startup, systemctl

I've got a Fedora 30 VM running on VirtualBox.  Trying to understand systemctl and run levels better, I ran

```bsh
sudo systemctl isolate reboot.target
```

As expected, the box restarted.  However, it doesn't ever get to the login screen.  Pressing Esc from the splash screen, which normally shows all of the steps in the startup process, only shows a blinking cursor.

If I restart the box again from VirtualBox, everything starts up normally.

Did restarting the box this way mess something up?

Comment: How many times did this occur? Does it happen every time you run systemctl isolate reboot.target?

Comment: Yeah, it did.  Restarting the normal way works fine.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem with my VM. Rebooting from the guest (fedora) with other commands makes it boot fine, but this one in particular makes it unbootable, is this right?

Comment: Yup, that’s correct.  More specifically, it caused the boot up process to hang.  Restarting from there (the normal way) fixed it.